# Conducting Quiz

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I want to conduct a quiz using silverlight.  This quiz contains few questions and each question will have multiple choices (Radio Buttons). User should select one answer. After completing the quiz I need to display Result.

Is it better to provide the questions and options in XML Document and then retrieve it into silverlight class? If yes, can anybody tell me the procedure to achieve it.

Comment: I am assuming that nobody knows solution.

Comment: Its not that nobody knows, its just that you didn't use the unversion `silverlight` tag.  Hence fewer people saw the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its better to store the questions/answers in a separate XML file.  You can then download the file using `WebClient` then de-seralise it to a collection of "Question" objects.  You can then display each question and the set of answers using something like a `DataForm`.